# Web.config -- Setting multiple attributes in different nodes based on a value in another node attribute value

Tags: xml, iis, xslt, web-config

Issue: I want to read a value in the web.config file and based on that value, transform a specific attribute in two other nodes where that attribute exists with a new attribute value.

Value to read: ClientName, can be ABCD or WXYZ. If it's WXYZ, then change....
Value to change: requireSSL from true if ClientName is ABCD or false if WXYZ.

This value will be in different nodes that are not child nodes of the ClientName node.

Here is what I'm trying to do:

**Old Web Config:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="ClientName" value="ABCD" />
    </appSettings>
    <system.web>
        <httpCookies requireSSL="true" />
        <authentication mode="Forms">
            <forms cookieless="UseCookies" enableCrossAppRedirects="true" defaultUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" protection="All" timeout="15" requireSSL="true" />
        </authentication>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

**New Web Config:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="ClientName" value="WXYZ" />
    </appSettings>
    <system.web>
        <httpCookies requireSSL="false" />
        <authentication mode="Forms">
            <forms cookieless="UseCookies" enableCrossAppRedirects="true" defaultUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" protection="All" timeout="15" requireSSL="false" />
        </authentication>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

*What do I want to do?* I want to read the value of the "ClientName" and if it's "WXYZ" then I want the "requireSSL" to be set to "false". However, if it's any other value ("ABCD" or anything else), then I want it to be "true".

I don't want to change the "CllientName" value. That will be set outside of this process. However, if it's "WXYZ", then I want the "requireSSL" to "false" and "true" otherwise.

To avoid confusion, I'm stating that I'm working with just "ABCD" here for the ClientName value. In my real-world, they're different, and the idea is when the transform detects that the ClientName is this particular value, then the transform occurs. Otherwise, it doesn't.

For most of our sites, we want requireSSL = true, but we have a couple of specific sites it needs to be false. I hope that make sense. Anyway, given the old web config as above, the idea is that based on the ClientName, I need the value to be true or false.

**This transform works, but it doesn't read any "ClientName" value:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
    <appSettings>
        <add key="ClientName" value="ABCD" />
    </appSettings>
    <system.web>
        <httpCookies requireSSL="false" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Condition(@requireSSL='true')" />
        <authentication mode="Forms">
            <forms cookieless="UseCookies" 
            enableCrossAppRedirects="true" 
            defaultUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" 
            loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" protection="All" 
            timeout="15" requireSSL="false"
            xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Location="Condition(@requireSSL='true')" />
        </authentication>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Therefore, this is more or less my starting point, but I don't know where to go from here. The [Learn Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/dd465326(v=vs.110)#using-transform-and-locator-attributes-on-separate-elements) site has a portion at the end of the page that shows a possible solution, but I'm just not groking it.

I'm using [this site](https://elmah.io/tools/webconfig-transformation-tester/) to test my transforms.

So far, I've tried this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform" xdt:Locator="Condition(@ClientName='ABCD')">
    <appSettings>
        <add key="ClientName" value="ABCD" />
    </appSettings>
    <system.web>
        <httpCookies requireSSL="false" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes(requireSSL)" />
        <authentication mode="Forms">
            <forms cookieless="UseCookies" 
            enableCrossAppRedirects="true" 
            defaultUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" 
            loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" protection="All" 
            timeout="15" requireSSL="false"
            xdt:Transform="SetAttributes(requireSSL)" />
        </authentication>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

This:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform" xdt:Locator="Condition(@ClientName='ABCD')">
    <appSettings>
        <add key="ClientName" value="ABCD" />
    </appSettings>
    <system.web>
        <httpCookies requireSSL="false" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" />
        <authentication mode="Forms">
            <forms cookieless="UseCookies" 
            enableCrossAppRedirects="true" 
            defaultUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" 
            loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" protection="All" 
            timeout="15" requireSSL="false"
            xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" />
        </authentication>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

This:

And this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform" xdt:Locator="XPath(configuration/appSettings/add[@key='ClientName' and @value='INEI'])">
    <appSettings>
        <add key="ClientName" value="INEI" />
    </appSettings>
    <system.web>
        <httpCookies requireSSL="false" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes(requireSSL)" />
        <authentication mode="Forms">
            <forms cookieless="UseCookies" 
            enableCrossAppRedirects="true" 
            defaultUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" 
            loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" protection="All" 
            timeout="15" requireSSL="false"
            xdt:Transform="SetAttributes(requireSSL)" />
        </authentication>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

All of these give no errors in the online test app, but I get the value of "true" throughout. I've done a bunch of other variations of this, but they all leave me with "true" at the requireSSL value.

I'm hoping that someone either knows exactly how to solve this and can provide the solution, or someone knows how this works and can tell me that this simply can't be done.

Comment: While asking an XSLT question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Input XML.
(2) Your logic, and XSLT that tries to implement it.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample XML in the #1 above.
(4) XSLT processor and its conformance with the XSLT standards: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, or 4.0.
All within the question as text, no images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following solution via XSLT 1.0

It is using a so called *Identity Transform* pattern.

**Input XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="ClientName" value="WXYZ"/>
    </appSettings>
    <system.web>
        <httpCookies requireSSL="true"/>
        <authentication mode="Forms">
            <forms cookieless="UseCookies" enableCrossAppRedirects="true" defaultUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" protection="All" timeout="15" requireSSL="true"/>
        </authentication>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

**XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8" omit-xml-declaration="no"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <!--Identity Transform pattern-->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@requireSSL">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="/configuration/appSettings/add[@key='ClientName' and @value='WXYZ']">
                <xsl:attribute name="requireSSL">
                    <xsl:text>false</xsl:text>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ClientName" value="WXYZ" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <httpCookies requireSSL="false" />
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms cookieless="UseCookies" enableCrossAppRedirects="true" defaultUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" protection="All" timeout="15" requireSSL="false" />
    </authentication>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Super useful information. I tried it in the Web.config tool I mentioned in my post (https://elmah.io/tools/webconfig-transformation-tester/). I'm not sure which standard it uses. It did not produce the expected results. I input the Input XML you provided as  well as the transform you provided and the requireSSL values were true after the processing.

Comment: You can try to find XSLT fiddle on Internet, and run it there

Comment: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/

Comment: Thanks. I put in your XML and transform here: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/b4FpKF and it does change the httpCookies node but not the forms node.

Comment: I adjusted the XSLT. Check it out now.

Comment: Thanks that works in the xlsfiddler now, but it still doesn't work in the web config transform tester. This gives me a place to start. I gave you a couple of thumbs up, but since the web.config test doesn't work, I'm going to leave it unanswered. Maybe someone has a solution and can assist? Thanks again for all the help.

Comment: Your question was about how to XSLT transform input XML into a desired output XML. I provided that answer. It will work with any XSLT processor. You shouldn't be stuck on the web config transform tester web based application.

Comment: Fair. I set it as answered. Thanks again.